# Not Found (#404) in Yii2

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, yii2

I am starting with Yii2, already installed XAMPP, created a basic project named 'yiidemo' with the help of Yii2 project template. Then access Gii by this URL http://localhost:8080/yiidemo/web/index.php?r=gii to generate a sample controller 'greeting', but when I click on 'Try it'  link, it is showing me following error message (url is http://localhost:8080/yiidemo/web/index.php?r=greeting ):

Not Found (#404)

This is the controllers\greetingController's code:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

class greetingController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('views/index');
    }

}
```

And this is the views\greeting\index.php code:

```
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
?>
<h1>greeting/index</h1>

<p>
    You may change the content of this page by modifying
    the file <code><?= __FILE__; ?></code>.
</p>
```

Can any body suggest how to get it worked with Yii2 hello world example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Controllers need to be all [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) and start with a capital letter. So in your case, `GreetingController` (both class and file).

And in your action use:

```
return $this->render('index');
```

See more about how to use this method [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#render%28%29-detail).

Comment: Thanks @Clyff, it works. I just missed the CamelCase.

Answer (score 1):

> Check your apache config file and make sure web directory is allowing override or not
>
> You can found config file in your ubuntu system here

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

> Few Linux system have config file on

```
 sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

> Just check your config file and **replace** **AllowOverride None with AllowOverride All**
>
> For example

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

> After saving file changes just **restart Apache server**

Answer (score 0):

Check that the file is saved as GreetingsController.php and not just GreetingsController (without .php)
Although this is not the mistake you made it still produces the same error message.